# Smarty: accessing a dynamically generated array?

Tags: smarty, smarty3, smarty2

My PHP code assigns an array to a Smarty variable that can be accessed in the following way:

```
{$foo.123.name}
{$foo.456.name}
...
```

The `123`, `456`, etc. indexes in the array are dynamically assigned (based on some logic that includes the database). Since they are dynamically assigned, I cannot just put `123`, etc. in the template file. However, those numbers are in another Smarty variable, say:

```
{$bar.id}
```

How do I use this `$bar.id` in place of the `123`, `456`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Smarty3:

```
{$foo.{$bar.id}.name}
```

For Smarty2:

```
{assign var="bid" value=$bar.id}
{$foo.$bid.name}
```